# not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x

сам код:

```
    x = str(input())
if (x % 4 == 0 and x % 4 != 0) or (x % 400 == 0):
    print ("Високосный")
else:
    print('Обычный')
```

трейсбек:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3eef3cea0d93> in <module>
      1 x = str(input())
----> 2 if (x % 4 == 0 and x % 4 != 0) or (x % 400 == 0):
      3     print ("Високосный")
      4 else:
      5     print('Обычный')

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

только учусь и не понимаю, в чем дело. x сконвертирован в int, но input почему-то, наверное, возвращает строку.

Comment: `x = int(input())`

Comment: все, заметила! спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input())   
if (x % 4 == 0 and x % 4 != 0) or (x % 400 == 0):  
    print ("Високосный")  
else:  
    print('Обычный')
```

`input()` введенные пользователем данные представляет в виде строки `str`